# AngularJS problems with ng-options selected value

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm facing a strange problem when using ng-options with AngularJS.

My scenario is pretty straight forward:

1. Bind a value with ng-model to be the selected option
2. Load the values of the 'select' from a backend
3. Bind the loaded values to the 'select'

My objects loaded from the backend is a key/value like:

```
{
   Value: "my_value",
   Name: "my_name"
}
```

And everything works fine... **Until Name and Value are the same.** Then angular won't bind the selected value correct anymore.

I have created this plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/tUBXIpMTBAHK2Xh8aDu6?p=preview
To demonstrate the problem.

My controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.values = [
        { Name: "Accepted", Value: "Accepted" },
        { Name: "Not accepted", Value: "NotAccepted" },
        { Name: "Not at all accepted", Value: "NotAtAllAccepted" }
      ];
  }, 2000);

  $scope.selectedValue = "Accepted";
  //$scope.selectedValue = "NotAccepted";
  //$scope.selectedValue = "NotAtAllAccepted";
});
```

If the selected value in the plunker example is set to 'Accepted' it will not work. But if the selected value is set to some of the other values - then it works fine.

And my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{selectedValue}}!</p>

    <select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="orderStatus.Value as orderStatus.Name for orderStatus in values"></select>

  </body>

</html>
```

Anyone who can enlighten me on this one?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

It looks like it works fine in Firefox. But in Chrome and IE the problem still occurres.

Comment: So when you view the plunkr example, the selected value in the dropdown is set to 'Accepted'?

Comment: I see a delay, but it works

Comment: When you say it works, I'm not sure we talk about the same. Is the selected value in the dropdown set to "Accepted" when you enter the page? No interaction with the page...

Comment: Are you using Firefox? Because it's actually working in Firefox, but not in Chrome or IE...

Comment: yes, I'm using Firefox

Answer (score 2):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.values = [
        { 'Name': "Accepted", 'Value': "Accepted" },
        { 'Name': "Not accepted", 'Value': "NotAccepted" },
        {'Name': "Not at all accepted", 'Value': "NotAtAllAccepted" }
      ];
    $scope.selectedValue = "Accepted";
  }, 2000);
  
  
  //$scope.selectedValue = "NotAccepted";
  //$scope.selectedValue = "NotAtAllAccepted";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{selectedValue}}!</p>
    
    <select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="orderStatus.Name as orderStatus.Value for orderStatus in values"></select>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The plunkr example is a simplified version of my code. I can't set the selectedValue inside the $timeout, because that logic is hidden in a service.

Comment: And if you try to run the code with selectedValue set to 'NotAccepted' outside the timeout. Everything works fine... It's only when the Value is the same as the Name there is a problem.