# Some prbm in angularjs lib default value is not working in select if(value and name) same?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Here I create sample for select in angular... Which is working fine.. I tried to set default value for select if I set this $scope.selectedValue = "SureshRaina";
working fine... but if I set this $scope.selectedValue = "Arun"; its not working... may i know what is problem in this example...

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.values = [
        { Name: "Arun", Value: "Arun" },
        { Name: "Suresh Raina", Value: "SureshRaina" },
        { Name: "Nelson Raj", Value: "NelsonRaj" }
      ];
  }, 2000);
  
  $scope.selectedValue = "Arun";
  //$scope.selectedValue = "SureshRaina";
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Sample Application</title>
     <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{selectedValue}}!</p>
    
    <select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="val.Value as val.Name for val in values"></select>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `track by val.Value` as you are using `select as` keyword inside your `ng-options` directive

```
ng-options="val.Value as val.Name for val in values track by val.Value"
```

[**Doc link**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-and-track-by-)

Comment: Hi @Pankaj,

I don't know why Suresh B has copied my question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742678/angularjs-problems-with-ng-options-selected-value

But setting track by val.Value doesn't work. It will work when name and value are the same, but not for the others. So setting the "track by" will cause the opposite problem (if you understand). You can try it in the plunkr example from my post.

Comment: @mikkelbm I understand what you are saying.. could you please provide a plunkr so that i can dig into it.?

Comment: Sure... Here you go: https://plnkr.co/edit/tUBXIpMTBAHK2Xh8aDu6?p=preview. I have now used "track by" in the HTML and set the selectedValue to a value where name and value are the same - it works. If you change the selectedValue to one of the others - it's not working anymore.

Comment: Hi @Pankaj, I hate to ask, but did you forget about this again? :) And do you have the time to take a look? Thanks...

Comment: @mikkelbm yeah..I didn't looked at it again..I will try to spend time with plunkr in my night :) :p